# Algorithm to check if Config B is a subset of Config A but not equal to Config A

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset

i need an algorithm to check if ConfigB is a subset of ConfigA but not equal to Config A.

The structur for my Config is :

- set of Providers (list element)
- set of Recipients(list element)
- set of Subscriptions(map)

As an example:
i have in ConfigA 5 Providers and 3 Recipients and 5 Subscriptions and in ConfigB i have 3 Providers and 2 Recipients and 2 Subscription and i want to check if ConfigB is a subset of ConfigA

Have you any ideas for an Algorithm for this construct?

i wrote an code to check both Configurations for equality:

```
    // looping through the first SubscriptionMap
  for (const auto& thisSubscription : this->m_subsriptions)
  {
    bool found = false;
    // looping through the second SubscriptionMap
    for (const auto& otherSubscription : other.m_subsriptions)
    {
      //comparing if the first and second SubscriptionMap are equals
      if (
        thisSubscription.first.first == otherSubscription.first.first &&
        thisSubscription.first.second == otherSubscription.first.second &&
        thisSubscription.second == otherSubscription.second
        )
        found = true;
    }
    if (!found)
      return false;
  }
  // comparing if ProviderInfos and RecipientInfos are equals
  if (m_providerInfos == other.m_providerInfos&&
    m_recipientInfos == other.m_recipientInfos)
    return true;

  return false;
```

now i need an contains Method to check if ConfigB is a subset of ConfigA but not equal to Config A i need ideas on how to handle this problem.

i hope i could be more specific :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you got stuck? Show us your code.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to find or reply a good answer, make it more clear

Comment: Hint:  First try to determine if a set of `T` is a proper subset  of another.  If you have problems with that, post some code.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes and downvotes - the question is quite clear (although showing actual code might get you better answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) for this. You'll just have to ensure the lists are sorted.